# How to make WebStorm's autocompletion work for external libraries?

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I'm a very new user of WebStorm and a very new TypeScript programmer. I'm trying to use typescript together with the library [libstl](http://vovazolotoy.github.io/). This is the code I currently have in the editor.

```
var PriorityQueue = require('libstl').PriorityQueue;

var queue = new PriorityQueue();
```

I'm able to compile to JavaScript without problems, but the autocompletion doesn't work for the methods of the variable `queue` (i.e. typing `queue.` doesn't show any of the methods it has, e.g. `enqueue()` or `dequeue()`).

How can I inform WebStorm of this library, so that it can show this methods in the autocompletion?

Answer (score 0):

Completion works fine for me in javascript files after installing libstl (`npm install libstl --save`). But WebStorm doesn't use node_modules when resolving CommonJS calls in typescript (moreover, 'require()' function itself is unknown to WebStorm unless you have node.d.ts available in your project). 
In general, I'd suggest using Typescript syntax in .ts files and JavaScript - in .js. For example, change your code as follows:

```
import PriorityQueue = require('./node_modules/libstl/Datastructures/PriorityQueue')

var queue = new PriorityQueue();
```